# How to know the percentage of git add . that is already processed?

Tags: git, repository, progress-bar, addition, percentage

I'm adding multiple and large files into a repo.

```
git add .
```

It is taking a lot of time. Is there any way I can display the progress bar, so that I can know how much of the files is already added to the repo?

Comment: which tool are you using for git management? Like - GitHub for windows... or editor git management?

Comment: I am using git bash (https://gitforwindows.org/) together with GitLab.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCneR.gif
git push already reports progress by default when it's run from a terminal

Comment: yes I know, I am asking for git add though.

Comment: Ask to know how many files you need to add?

Comment: @rajibkarmaker the op is asking about “add to staging” not “pushing”

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónR. it's a lot - around 8k

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No progress-bar, but, at least, you will get some feedback and see which files have already been added:

```
 git add --verbose .
```

Comment: not exactly what I wanted, but this helped - did upvote

Comment: Thanks @vanilla, I know. Maybe `pv` (pipe viewer) could help to get what you want.

Comment: does verbose also work with other commands such as commit, etc.?

Comment: @vanilla Yes, other commands support the verbose option too. But the actual behavior varies from command to command. commit, for example, adds the diff to the commit message.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a one-liner, that calculates the progress percentage every second:

```
git add --verbose . > ../progress.txt & percent=0; while [[ $percent -le 99 && $percent -ge 0 ]]; do num1=$(cat ../progress.txt | wc -l); num2=$(find . -type f -not -path "./.git/*" | wc -l); percent=$((num1*100 / (num2 - 3) )); echo $percent"%"; sleep 1; done; echo "DONE"; sleep 1; rm ../progress.txt
```

- While the progress less than 100%
- Count the lines what `git add` generated ( *num1* )
- Count the all files in the folder except `.git/*` ( *num2* )
- Calculate percentage based on these numbers ( *num1*100 / num2* )

  - We should subtract 3 from *num2*, because the find command echoes more lines than expected
- the script generates a temporary progress.txt file, but it removes at the end

Example output:

```
12%
25%
50%
50%
75%
75%
100%
```

Comment: This one will create progress.txt in the repository you adding files into. Isn't that file will be added to the repo too?

Comment: @Krypt the `git add` executes before the creation of `progress.txt` - but for maximum security I modified the path to `../progress.txt` so it creates this temporary file outside the git repo

Comment: I used this command (in form before edit). It did, in fact, added progress.txt